# Запихнуть код прогноза погоды в кнопку телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть код прогноза погоды, мне надо что бы когда я в меню бота нажимал на кнопку "Прогноз погоды" бот присылал сообщ, введите город, ты вводишь город и он присылает по коду погоду,

```
dp.message_handler()
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
    code_to_smie = {
        "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
        "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
        "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
        "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
        "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
    }

    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_token}&units=metric"    
        )
        data = r.json()

        city = data["name"]
        cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]

        weather_description = data["weather"][0]["main"]
        if weather_description in code_to_smie:
            wd = code_to_smie[weather_description]
        else:
            wd = "Посмотри в окно, не пойму что там за погода!"

        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]

        await message.reply(f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}° {wd}\n"
            f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/c\nХорошего дня!")


    except:
        await message.reply('Проверьте название города')
```

помогите плиз, пробовал что в моих силах, не додумался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно изучить состояния в aiogram, так называемый FSM (Final State Machine).

В интернете есть достаточно информации про эти состояния, в официальной документации есть хороший [пример](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html).

А вообще логика работы такова:

1. Составить список стэйтов (в вашем случае достаточно одного - это город)

```
class Town(StatesGroup):
    town = State()
```

2. Написать обработчик - в него нужно будет передать помимо аргумента `message` ещё и аргумент `state`, а в сам декоратор указать тот `state`, на который нужно перейти. Например:

```
async def test(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите свой город")
    await Town.town.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Town.town)
async def get_town(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ваш город это - {message.text}")
    await state.finish()
```

Также в каждый `state` можно записывать какую-то информацию, и извлекать в любом другом заданном вами `state` (явно - это просто словарь, который выделяется для каждого юзера).